# to make this code simpler

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code, recorded from macros. I have to copy the code again and again
to make the process finish.

Please help me to make a loop until the process finishes.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D2:E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ALB1").Select
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D3:E3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ALB2").Select
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    '
    '
    '
    '
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D127:E127").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ALB126").Select
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the essential difference between this question, and your [earlier one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404874/repeating-macro-code)?

Comment: You need to do some work - what have you tried? where are you stuck? Have you searched the web for the syntax of worksheets and ranges and loops? We are willing to help but we need to know what you know and what you don't. We cannot teach you how to program if you do not have the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim Sh1 As WorkSheet, Sh2 As WorkSheet
  Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set Sh2 = Sheets("ALB1")

  Dim R As Long
  For R = 2 to 127
    Sh1.Range("D" & R & ":E" & R).Copy Sh2.Range("C" & R - 1)
  Next R
End Sub
```

Or even better:

```
Sheets("ALB1").Range("C1:D126") = "=Sheet1!D2"
```

Assigning a formula that works on the first cell of a range to the whole range is equivalent to typing the formula on the first cell and copying it right and down.

Comment: Thank you sir for replying me, however the code given is not work as i wanted to be. i have many sheets tabs, name from ALB1 to ALB126. the data is copied row by row to respective sheet, in location C1.

actually i dont have any basic of the VBA code.

thank you for help. :)

Comment: finally i found the solution of my problem, here it is.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution of my problems
here it is

```
Sub Check_After()
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet
Dim lCount As Long
Dim lCountA As Long
Dim lCountB As Long
Dim lNum As Long

lCount = 0
lCountA = 2
lCountB = 1

lNum = 127
Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Sh2 = Sheets("ALB" & lCountB)
Do
    Set Sh2 = Sheets("ALB" & lCountB)
    Sh1.Range("D" & lCountA & ":E" & lCountA).Copy Sh2.Range("C1")

    lNum = lNum - 1
    lCount = lCount + 1


    lCountA = lCountA + 1
    lCountB = lCountB + 1

Loop Until lNum = 1
MsgBox "The Do Until loop made " & lCount & " loop(s)."
```

End Sub